# Capturing counter value in Javascript closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code creates 10 elements under `<body id="container" />`. When i click on any element, I always see an alert with the value `10`.

**How can I get each alert to show the index of each element?**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  var id = "#element_" + i;
  $("#container").append('<p id="element_' + i + '">foo</p>');
  $(id).click(function (e) {
    alert(i);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to create a private closure

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    (function(idx){
        var id = "#element_" + idx;
        $("#container").append('<p id="element_' + idx + '">foo</p>');
        $(id).click(function (e) {
            alert(idx);
        });
    })(i)
}
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tCObKUCS8WRSFtYmwVbc?p=preview)

Comment: we at SO is improving at how to downvote an answer simply because somebody doesn't like an answer.... where as the [down-vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) says `Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect`

Comment: Not my dv, but the title of the down-vote button says "This answer is not useful" :)

Comment: @Jack how is it not useful? it is a working solution... may not be the best one

Comment: It solves the problem, that's not my point; the tooltip of the actual button has that content, which is substantially different from the faq/help content.

Comment: @Jack that I understood... still if a person has to downvote he/she need to find the answer as `not useful` right... my question is how he/she might has found it as not useful

Comment: Well, in this case, I wouldn't know why someone would feel it's not useful; maybe they expected more explanation?

Comment: @Jack might be... I didn't give much explanation because OP used the term closure... thought the OP will understand it

Comment: @Jack this was useful. usually people do explain why not useful.

Answer (score 4):

You need either closure or simply use [$.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with data:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  var id = "#element_" + i;
  $("#container").append('<p id="element_' + i + '">foo</p>');
  $(id).on("click", i, function (e) { alert(e.data); });
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `.on()` first and then `.appendTo()` while caching `$('#container')`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't make functions inside `for` loops

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  $("#container").append('<p id="element_' + i + '">foo</p>');
}

$("#container > p").click(function (e) {
    var idNum = this.id.split('_')[1];
    alert(idNum); // 0, 1, 2 ...
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oFEZ/3/edit)**